# Use Netbeans Ide for HTML Project with NO Java

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans

I don't know who to ask or where to post this question: I have a Html project (html, css, php, javascript, mysql) which I edit with Notepad++. The project works OK so far, except the typing error correction & debugging is very basic (print statements in PHP, Firefox in-built debugger for Javascript, no on-line help when typing source code).

I would like to switch to the NetBeans IDE for this project, hoping the IDE  will help me be more productive. I don't know Java and don't want to learn it. I am not a longtime Web Developer, this (Web projects development) is only temporary.

Is that possible ? Do you know a link to a tutorial for what I want ? If not here, where can I ask this question ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to open Netbeans and create a project in that? You can select the language to be php and create project from existing code. Then select the root folder of your project. It will create project for you hopefully!

Comment: Yes, I will try that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no reason to learn java if you want use Netbeans as your favorite IDE.**

[Netbeans Download Options](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) . You should download the HTML5/JavaScript version which comes for support for html,css,javascript and php.

However, you need the JDK (JavaDevelopmentKit) installed on your machine **as Netbeans needs Java to run** , not you. I'm using netbeans and is very useful. I decide to download the version for all the the supported languages since i start developing plugins for cordova (java).

Netbeans definitely will help you to be productive according to what you use (PHP,HTML and Javascript).

Comment: Yes, (I think) that's what I have installed: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_60; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.60-b23
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_60-b27
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_GB (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1
Cache directory: C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1

Comment: Just a note, for HTML development NetBeans are fine with just JRE, JDK is needed only for Java-related development. If you download a PHP or HTML5 distribution from http://netbeans.org/downloads/ , it is already bundled with JRE and can be run out of the box

Comment: Thanks everybody !